# Jump to next white space

Tags: vim

Instead of using <kbd>w</kbd> to jump to the beginning of the next word or using <kbd>e</kbd> to jump to the end of the next word I want to have a shortcut which jumps to the next whitespace between words.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

- Use <kbd>f</kbd> and then <kbd>space</kbd>. See `:help f` and `:help t` for that.
- Alternatively use `/[[:space:]]` or `/\s` if you want to also match tab.
- otherwise <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> will do it (capital e and lowercase L).

Following a suggested edit that was rejected, here is how to do it backwards (jump to previous space):

- Use <kbd>F</kbd> and then <kbd>space</kbd>. See `:help F` and `:help T` for that.
- Alternatively use `?[[:space:]]` or `?\s` if you want to also match tab.
- otherwise <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> will do it (capital b and lowercase h).

Comment: Works great. I created a mapping in my ~.vimrc so that I have just press f to jump in the next white space nmap f f<space>
vmap f f<space>

Comment: I am sure you used `nnoremap` and `vnoremap` instead of `nmap` and `vmap` otherwise you would get an infinite recursion.

Comment: Actually I used nmap and vmap, but I will change to the commands you mentioned and see what will happen. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: There is no need for `:noremap` in this case (although it's a good thing to know it exists), because the rhs is only at the beginning of the lhs, see `:help recursive_mapping`

Comment: @EI Isra You are wrong: there is no need to use `:*map` instead of `:*noremap` in this case. When you write a mapping you should think about using `nore` version in a first place because it is less prone to errors that may arise after executing `*map` command somewhere else.

Comment: you can also use `/\s` or `?\s` to match any whitespace character.  Remapping 'f' like that removes its usefulness for non space characters, that can't be desirable!  I use f and family as much as any other key, "delete up to the next period", etc.

Comment: I find this useful sometimes: with MacVim in OSX you can use `Alt` + `Right` then `Left` to jump to the next word and then back one char.

Comment: Once you've used `f<Space>` or `F<Space>` to jump to a space, you can use `;` to jump to the next space or `,` to jump to the previous space.

Comment: The most important part of this answer was `B` and `E`. I had no idea about them

Answer (score 16):

On the same line :

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> will work.

Generally, <kbd>f</kbd>+`<char>` allows you to jump on the next character on the same line.

See `:help f` for more information.

Answer (score 15):

as mentioned: you can use `f` and then `Space` but then use `;` to hop to all the remaining spaces.
My sequence is then often:

`f<Space>;;;;`

The semicolon is a repetition for the f-key (find char in Line)