# Jump to previous white space in vim/gvim

Tags: vim

Instead of using 'b' to jump to the previous word I want to have a shortcut which jumps to the previous white space between words.

Matthias.

Comment: You should group your questions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use  `F <space>` to jump to the previous white space, and `f <space>` to jump to the next. To repeat those commands in the same direction, use `;`, or use `,` to repeat them in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 6):

1 hour ago you asked about [next white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432837/jump-to-next-white-space-in-vim-gvim). You should group your questions.

So: same as previously: `Bh`.

Comment: This is the proper and exact answer. The others seem like a tweak as compared to this.

Answer (score 3):

Capital <kbd>F</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> will move the cursor to the nearest previous space. If you want to keep moving backwards this way you can use <kbd>;</kbd>

Comment: and `,` will move you the other direction if you overshoot with `;`.